# What's the correct syntax for overriding a parent Var?

Tags: objective-c, swift3, overriding

**Goal:** Using Swift 3.0.1 to override UIViewController's transitioningDelegate; based on Objective-C model. That is, translating Objective-C into its Swift 3.0.1 equivalent.  
[Apple transitioningDelegate  Reference](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621421-transitioningdelegate?language=objc)

**Objective-C**

```
- (void)setTransitioningDelegate:(id<UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate>)transitioningDelegate
{
    super.transitioningDelegate = transitioningDelegate;
    self.presentationController.delegate = self;
}
```

**Swift 3.0**

[image]

Is this the correct syntax? 
Why am I getting the compiler error?

Comment: Perhaps your answer is in [these search results](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bswift%5D+override+setter).

Comment: `override var transitioningDelegate: UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate?{
        
        get{
            
            return super.transitioningDelegate
        
        }set{
            
            self.presentationController?.delegate = self;
        
        }
    }`